# Installing dkms fails on bone stock Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, xubuntu, dependencies, dkms

I *just* installed Xubuntu 20.04, and did an initial `sudo apt upgrade`, then rebooted. Now, I'm trying to install `dkms`, and am greeted with this. What gives?

```
~$ sudo apt-get install dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dkms : Depends: gcc but it is not going to be installed or
                 c-compiler
        Depends: dpkg-dev but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: make or
                 build-essential but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: fakeroot
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I'm hesitant to try fixing broken stuff, when nothing should be broken. This is a bone stock install!

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`? Are you connected to internet?

Comment: @Pilot6 yep I did. However I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to install a package from a `.deb` file, which failed to configure because it was missing `dkms`, which is why I was trying to install `dkms`. When I purged the unconfigured package and tried again to install `dkms`, it worked fine.

Not sure why having an unconfigured package breaks the ability to install other packages....

Comment: You could run `sudo apt install -f` as it was suggested.